# Decoding pictures in Swift doesn't work in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsdata, decoding

I have a problem here. I have an array with custom objects, that contain pictures. When i install my app to my phone all pictures are at their place, but when i try to save changes to my array with UserDefaults - all is saving, except pictures. I have found tha the problem is with decoding pictures. They all change to placeholder picture. Can anybody help me and say whats wrong?

```
 required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    englishWord = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .englishWord)
    belarusianWord = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .belarusianWord) ?? ""
    englishDefinition = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .englishDefinition) ?? ""
    belarusianDefinition = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .belarusianDefinition) ?? ""

    let data = try container.decodeIfPresent(Data.self, forKey: CodingKeys.wordImage)
    if let data = data {
        guard let wordImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "Error decoding logo", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        self.wordImage = wordImage
    } else {
        wordImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder")!
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let data = UIImage().pngData()
    try container.encode(data, forKey: CodingKeys.wordImage)
    try container.encode(self.englishWord, forKey: .englishWord)
    try container.encode(self.belarusianWord, forKey: .belarusianWord)
    try container.encode(self.englishDefinition, forKey: .englishDefinition)
    try container.encode(self.belarusianDefinition, forKey: .belarusianDefinition)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `encode(to:)` method, simply replace

```
let data = UIImage().pngData()
```

with

```
let data = self.wordImage.pngData()
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped, but now there is another problem. UserDefaults are not working anymore. They cant save changes.

Answer (score 0):

After answers of people above i have another problem. My UserDefaults stopped working.

```
class FilesManager: NSObject {
static let shared = FilesManager()
private override init() {}

func saveData(data: Data, completion: (()->())?) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/words.dat"

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsPath) {
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: documentsPath,
                                       contents: nil,
                                       attributes: nil)
    } else {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: documentsPath)
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: documentsPath,
                                           contents: nil,
                                           attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("File replacing failed: \(error)")
        }
    }

    let file: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: documentsPath)
    if file != nil {
        file?.write(data)
        file?.closeFile()
        print("Data saved to file")
        if let completion = completion {
            completion()
        }
    } else {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong!")
    }
}

func loadData() -> Data? {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/words.dat"

    let file: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: documentsPath)
    if file != nil {
        let data = file?.readDataToEndOfFile()
        file?.closeFile()
        print("Data loaded from file")
        return data
    }
    else {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong!")
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

if `let data = UIImage().pngData()` stays, everything works well!